# Used Background for some Scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, scenarios

```
    Feature: list video in stored

      Background:
       Given I have the following videos
          | title                              | format   |
          | Running Central Park in the Fall   | BluRay   |
          | Running Glacier Park in the Spring | Download |
          | Running Balboa Park in the Winter  | DVD      |

    Scenario: list videos in stored   
      When I am on the "video" page
      Then I should see "Running Central Park in the Fall"
      Then I should see "Running Glacier Park in the Spring"
      Then I should see "Running Balboa Park in the Winter"

   Scenario: Page links
     When I view all videos from page "1"
     Then I should not see "Cycling Utah in the Spring"
     Then I should not see "Touring Utah in the Spring"
     Then I should see "Previous"
     Then I should see "1"
     Then I should see "2"
     Then I should see "Next"

   Scenario: Show a message when there is no video
     When I am on the "video" page
     Then I should see "No videos"
```

I want used background for Scenario: "list videos in stored" and "Page links" but exclusion Scenario: "Show a message when there is no video". Please support me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 2 features one with background and scenario, the other without background

```
    Feature: list video in stored

      Background:
       Given I have the following videos
          | title                              | format   |
          | Running Central Park in the Fall   | BluRay   |
          | Running Glacier Park in the Spring | Download |
          | Running Balboa Park in the Winter  | DVD      |

    Scenario: list videos in stored   
      When I am on the "video" page
      Then I should see "Running Central Park in the Fall"
      Then I should see "Running Glacier Park in the Spring"
      Then I should see "Running Balboa Park in the Winter"

   Scenario: Page links
     When I view all videos from page "1"
     Then I should not see "Cycling Utah in the Spring"
     Then I should not see "Touring Utah in the Spring"
     Then I should see "Previous"
     Then I should see "1"
     Then I should see "2"
     Then I should see "Next"

Feature: list video in stored without video
   Scenario: Show a message when there is no video
     When I am on the "video" page
     Then I should see "No videos"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but we can't put 2 Feature in a file. I don't want splitting it into 2 files.

Comment: Nam, then you are going to have to remove the background and make it a step in the first two qualifying scenarios.